# Django: Field 'X' doesn't have a default value

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

The models.py of my table is :

```
class TestCaseGlobalMetricData(models.Model):
    testRunData = models.ForeignKey(TestRunData)
    testCase = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cvmTotalFree = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    systemFree = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sharedMemory = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And the part of the code which uses this table is

```
TestCaseGlobalMetricData(testRunData=testRunDataObj,
                    testCase=tokens['tc_name'],
                    timestamp=tokens['timestamp'],
                    cvmTotalFree=totalFree).save()
```

When this line is executed the following error is seen,

```
File "/web/memmon/eink-memmon/projects/process.py", line 382, in process_cvm_usage
    cvmTotalFree=totalFree).save()

.....

Warning: Field 'sharedMemory' doesn't have a default value
```

I tried inserting into the table using the `python manage.py shell` and it works fine.

The schema of the table as seen in mysql is

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| testRunData_id  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| testCase        | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| cvmTotalFree    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| systemFree      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| sharedMemory    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Note:
The field `sharedMemory` was added in the `models.py` today. I did proper migrations using `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.

Comment: If you have recently added the default value you need to execute `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: @Gocht: Thanks for your comment. As is said in note, i did that.

Comment: if this is still relevant (I doubt it) you should add null=True, blank=True to the field.